# why ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60) doesn't work?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, ini-set

the default expire time of session is 1440,i want to reduce this time to 60 second,but when i use `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime','60')` in the first page it work,but it doesn't work in an other page,
please tell me what is my wrong?

```
    ----------index.php-----------
    <?php
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime','60');
    session_start();       

    $_SESSION['id']='123';

    print('<br/><a href="link.php">link<a/>');
    ?>


    ----------link.php----------
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60);
    }else{
        header('Location:index.php?ERROR');
    }

    print('<br/><a href="link.php?1">menu<a/>');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because garbage collector starts (if starts) **before** session

So setting `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60);` after `session_start()` changes nothing

Answer (score 4):

The session garbage collector will fire as part of `session_start()`. Since you're changing the setting **AFTER** you start a session, you're too late to change the settings.