# Why gc_maxlifetime wins over sess_expiration?

Tags: php, codeigniter

gc_maxlifetime is already set to 24 minutes, but when each application has a different sess_expiration. One of them is set to 9000 seconds (2 1/2 hours). The app is expired based on gc_maxlifetime not sess_expiration. Why is that? How can the sess_expiration work if it is longer than gc_maxlifetime?

Comment: Check [official documentation and comments bellow](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from here: [why ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',60) doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032306/why-ini-setsession-gc-maxlifetime-60-doesnt-work) and here: https://www.dev-metal.com/how-the-php-session-garbage-collector-really-works/

> Because garbage collector starts (if starts) before session

I think that the gc_maxlifetime fires before your CI session handler and for this it 'wins'.

For not being forced to modify your `php.ini` file, you could try to set it before each session_start:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
session_start();
```

Or in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 7200
```

You could read more here: [Codeigniter increase session time out not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751849/codeigniter-increase-session-time-out-not-working)

Hope it helps!

Comment: GC is run after session initialization, and both of these INIs are overriden by CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Not really as simple as you've put it ...

It **is** true that `gc_maxlifetime` is what determines if a session should be deleted or not, because that's effectively the "server-side timer" that counts towards the deletion of a session - there's one on the client side as well, because that's where cookies are stored.
However, CodeIgniter will set `gc_maxlifetime` to the same value that you put in `sess_expiration`, *unless it is 0* (in which case it uses your php.ini value).

But something else in your question may be important:

> but when each application has a different sess_expiration. One of them is set to 9000 seconds (2 1/2 hours)

If you are using the same `sess_save_path`, `sess_cookie_name`, `sess_match_ip` on the same server, but for multiple applications ... then the application with the lowest `sess_expiration` value will at some point delete sessions that you intended to be still valid for others.

TL;DR: Don't use the same session "space" for separate applications.